Show the relation between the derivative of a curve and Lie bracket
I'm solving this Problem: Let X and Y be vector fields over $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\phi_t,\psi_s$ the local flow respectively. For all $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there is an open intervall $I_p\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $0\in I_p$, s.t. $c_p(t):=\psi_{-t}\circ\phi_{-t}\circ\psi_t\circ\phi_t(p)$ defines a curve $c_p: I\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
$$
\dot{c}_p(0)=0 ,\  \frac{1}{2}\ddot{c}_p(0)=[X,Y]_p
$$
There's a hint which says consider the map $b:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)^2\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with $b(s,t):=\psi_{-s}\circ\phi_{-t}\circ\psi_s\circ\phi_t(p)$, and use chain rule to express the derivative of $c_p$ as combination of derivatives of $b$.
I'm considering to use the hint. But I'm stucked in the first step. The curve $c_p$ is composed of maps, which are diffeomorphisms on the manifold, not functions which maps a real number to a point on manifold. So the chain rule don't work here, and I don't know how to reform the expression of $c_p(t)$ so that I can use the chain rule.

Write $\psi_{-t}(q) = \psi(-t, q)$. Your expression is $c_p(t) = \psi(-t, q(t))$, where $q(t) = \phi(-t, \psi(t, \phi(t, p)))$. Applying the chain rule is theoretically straightforward here (I haven't tried it though), i.e.
$$c_p'(t) = -D_t\psi(-t, q(t)) + D_q\psi(-t, q(t))q'(t) = \dots$$
Note
$$D_t\phi(0, q) = X(q),$$
$$D_q \phi(0, q) = I,$$
and similarly for $\psi$.

I see. But can you tell me how can this connected to partial derivatives of b(s,t)? And should I see psi(t, q) as a function R to R^n, or R^{1+n} to R^n?

$\psi : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. I wrote the important identites to use when you plug $t = 0$. You get a lot of simplification.

what you mean by $D_q\phi(0,q)=I$? Is it 1, not the identical map? And the notation $D_q\psi$ makes me also a little confused: the second argument of $\psi$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but normally I only see such notation for partial derivatives, namly derivative by a component which is in $\mathbb{R}$ e.g. $D_t\psi$.

$D_q$ is the derivative with respect to $q \in \mathbb{R^n}$. That is, $\phi(t, q + h) = \phi(t, q) + D_q\phi(t, q)h + o(|h|)$.
